# Why does Tex stop rendering after a writing post for a while? How do I fix it?

Tags: support, mathjax

This frequently happens to me. I am in my zone writing a long and detailed description in my post, and suddenly the Tex stop rendering in the display section.

This is rather annoying because I do not trust my ability to write long tex without making mistakes.

Is this normal?? If so, Is there a setting I can change so that tex renders automatically ALL the time?

Comment: Try refreshing the page. To make sure you don't lose the content entered so far, select it all, copy, then paste after refresh. (The latter may not be necessary because drafts are saved periodically, but it's better to be safe.)

Comment: Thanks. But that is essentially what I do all the time, which I find troublesome. It works mostly when I cut my article out of the input box and paste it back in, although sometimes refreshing works too.

Comment: Unless you're working with one of those top-of-the-line i7 processors with 16gb of ram and a your pagefile is sitting on an SSD drive... having automatic rendering is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: When I tackle "long and detailed" write-ups for Math.SE, I sometimes prefer to do the drafting (particularly of intermediate changes) in StackEdit.  I'm not sure if you've seen a change in MathJax behavior, or if your baseline of observations is just too short for changes to be observed.